# prevent page refresh on php while I click browser back option

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form created in HTML.the form values passed second page via post method.in that page I put the edit button while I click that button to redirect the HTML form page with user typed values.now my problem is how to prevent the page reloaded in PHP or JAVASCRIPT

Comment: You can make use of `onbeforeunload` event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onbeforeunload?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.onbeforeunload

Comment: Can you explain a little more? Do you want to avoid the post call happening again?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.

When the form is submitted as a POST request, your PHP scripts sends a redirect response to the client, which causes the result to be fetched with a new GET request.

This avoids the resubmit of a form when the refresh button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with JavaScript using window.history.

See [Manipulating the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

However, your original form should get the saved values from a database. There's no guarantee that sending the user back a page will not cause the page to reload. It depends on the browser.

If this is your edit button

```
<button id="editButton">Edit</button>
```

Then your JS would look something like:

```
document.getElementById('editButton').onclick = function(event){
  event.preventDefault(); 
  window.history.back();
return false;
}
```

Comment: hi Chad Hedgcock your idea is working in firefox.but not working in chrome browser please help me

Comment: ...as in it won't go back or that the form isn't filled when they do?